# Python+django - some problems with using css javascript and images

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I enter to my site, css javascript and images doesn't works. And when i try enter like administrator (http:/mysite/admin) I have error "Site matching query does not exist". It happens after transition from SQLite and Python 3.3 to MySQL and Python 2.7.
error code:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
March 18, 2014 - 23:54:12
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'payforward.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6375
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:40] "GET /media/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 500 79587
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] ��������� �� ����� ����-
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:40] "GET /media/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52926)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] ��������� �� ����� ����-
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:40] "GET /media/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css HTTP/1.1" 500 79984
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10054] 
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:40] "GET /media/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52930)
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
----------------------------------------
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10054] 
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:40] "GET /media/css/slider.css HTTP/1.1" 500 79604
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:40] "GET /media/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 500 79506
[18/Mar/2014 23:54:51] "GET /media/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 500 79626
```

What it can be?
Help me please!

Comment: Compare the django_site table in both databases and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: Check if {{STATIC_URL}} was missing or not?

Comment: STATIC_URL is OK. Before transition from SQLite and Python 3.3 to MySQL and Python 2.7 everything works

Comment: Done. It's problem on Python 2.7. When I try Python 3.3 it works.

Comment: What do you try on ('127.0.0.1', 52926)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try install django on Python 3 and do all staff step by step